# jQuery - if select one option is selected, make input required

Tags: jquery

today I'am stuck. I am quite new in jQuery and I wonder if there is a option to check with jQuery if one option is selected then i need input make required, but only for one option.

```
<label for="lname">Delivery Method</label>
<select name="delivery"> 
<option value="Phone">Home</option>
<option value="Phone">Take away</option>
</select>
<label for="lname">Adress</label>
<input type="text" id="lname" name="lname"><br><br>
```

My request is that if the Home option is selected, then the Address will require. Sorry for my bad English, but I am trying my best!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a simple example:

```js
$('#delivery').on('change', function() {
  if (this.value === 'home') {
    $('#lname').prop('required', true);
  } else {
    $('#lname').prop('required', false);
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<label for="lname">Delivery Method</label>
<select name="delivery" id='delivery'>
  <option value selected></option>
  <option value="home">Home</option>
  <option value="takeaway">Take away</option>
</select>
<label for="lname">Adress</label>
<input type="text" id="lname" name="lname"><br><br>
```

What have I done:

- Add `id` to delivery `select`
- Change `value` of home and take away `option` because was same (How did you plan to tell them apart?).
- Create a simple on change event

---

Pure JS solution (You don't need jQuery `:)`)

```js
const delivery = document.getElementById('delivery');
const lname = document.getElementById('lname');
delivery.addEventListener('change', () => {
  if (delivery.value === 'home') {
    lname.required = true;
  } else {
    lname.required = false;
  }
});
```

```html
<label for="lname">Delivery Method</label>
<select name="delivery" id='delivery'>
  <option value selected></option>
  <option value="home">Home</option>
  <option value="takeaway">Take away</option>
</select>
<label for="lname">Adress</label>
<input type="text" id="lname" name="lname">
```

[You might not need jQuery](http://youmightnotneedjquery.com/)

---

A great tip from @Rory McCrossan, use directly result of `if equal` for change result of require like:

**Jquery**

```js
$('#delivery').on('change', function() {
  $('#lname').prop('required', this.value === 'home');
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<label for="lname">Delivery Method</label>
<select name="delivery" id='delivery'>
  <option value selected></option>
  <option value="home">Home</option>
  <option value="takeaway">Take away</option>
</select>
<label for="lname">Adress</label>
<input type="text" id="lname" name="lname"><br><br>
```

**Pure js**

```js
const delivery = document.getElementById('delivery');
const lname = document.getElementById('lname');
delivery.addEventListener('change', () => {
  lname.required = delivery.value === 'home';
});
```

```html
<label for="lname">Delivery Method</label>
<select name="delivery" id='delivery'>
  <option value selected></option>
  <option value="home">Home</option>
  <option value="takeaway">Take away</option>
</select>
<label for="lname">Adress</label>
<input type="text" id="lname" name="lname">
```

Comment: Or just `$('#lname').prop('required', this.value === 'home');` / `lname.required = delivery.value === 'home';`

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan I never thought about it, thanks `:)`